# Python tutorial says that "5" * 5 should be 55, but my result is '55555'

Tags: python

I'm following Xerotic's Python guide on HF and it tells me to do:

```
x = 5
y = "5"
print x * 5
print y * 5
```

and it should print:

```
25
55
```

However mine prints `'55555'`. What is happening here?

Comment: If "Xerotic's Python guide on HF" says that `y*5` should print `55`, the guide is wrong.  Are you sure the guide says `y*5` and not `y*2`?

Comment: I didn't even know that you can use the `*` on a string. Seems to duplicate the string by the number that follows it.

Comment: It's nice that the tutorial is locked behind a forum registration...

Comment: Sounds like a bad tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is an int
`y` is a string
`x*5` is a numerical computation, so it is `25`
`y*5` means repeat the string `y` 5 times

What you want is:

```
print x*5
print y*2
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate the answer :D